# Best place to be kept updated on security flaws in softwares

Tags: security, open-source

Where should one go to be kept updated on all of the security flaws/problems floating around? Specially in the era of open source where we tend to use libraries from everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Defense Information Systems Agency - Information Assurance Support Environment](http://iase.disa.mil/index2.html)
- [Defense Information Systems Agency - Security Technical Implementation Guides](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/index.html)
- [Defense Information Systems Agency - Security Readiness Review Evaluation Scripts](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/SRR/index.html)

I find these links useful as a defense contractor, but they might have use for civilian applications as well. Look at the SRR scripts as a way to detect possible vulnerabilities on a system you are trying to secure.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick list:

- [CVE](http://cve.mitre.org/)
- [Security Focus](http://www.securityfocus.com/vulnerabilities)
- [Secunia](http://secunia.com/)
- [CERT](http://www.cert.org/)
- [FrSIRT](http://www.frsirt.com/english/)
- [SecWatch](http://secwatch.org/)
- [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Vulnerability)